# How to use json output of azure Microsoft Translator Text with javascript in nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, azure, microsoft-translator

I use [this code](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-NodeJS/blob/master/Translate.js)! for querying translation through Microsoft Azure Translator Text.

This line

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
```

prints in the console for the input text 'bonjour':

```
[
    {
        "detectedLanguage": {
            "language": "fr",
            "score": 1
        },
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hello",
                "to": "en"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get the string 'Hello' by parsing the result this way :

```js
console.log(body.translations.text)
```

I got this in the console :

```
console.log(body.translations.text)
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of text like this:

```
console.log(body[0].translations[0].text);
```

[image]

body is an array, so you need to get the value in the array by using index, body[0].

**Update:**
I just ran the whole code provided by that link, it also works fine.

```
request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
    console.log(body[0].translations[0].text);
  });
```

Comment: I tested it. Same issue : ```console.log(body[0].translations[0].text);
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations' of undefined```

Comment: @Jidé Isn't your body=`[
    {
        "detectedLanguage": {
            "language": "fr",
            "score": 1
        },
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hello",
                "to": "en"
            }
        ]
    }
]`